# App store reject - remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key

Tags: ios

app store rejected my app. because it has the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

But I already removed it.
All *.plist of my app doesn't have any 'UIBackgroundModes' keys.

then, How can I remove the `audio` setting from the UIBackgroundModes keys?

Here is screenshot from `Capabilities`

[image: No capabilities]

Comment: Not sure why you were down-voted.. However, try checking your App's entitlements. Also if it was rejected for `UIBackgroundModes`, then that is in your `info.plist` which is not the same as your capabilities.

Comment: @Brandon  where can I check that `App's entitlements`? unfortunately my `info.plist` doesn't have any `UIBackgroundModes` keys anymore. I deleted it.

Comment: Ok so if you removed it, Go to Xcode organizer, Export for AppStore instead of uploading. Make a copy of the IPA that you just exported. Change the copy's extension to `.zip`. Unzip the file and go to `Payload`. Find "Info.plist" and check if the background mode is still in there. Also find a file with the extension `.entitlements` and check what is in it (if it exists).

Comment: @Brandon thank you for advice. I opened `info.plist` from `IPA`. It doesn't have any `UIBackgroundMode` keys.

Comment: @Brandon thank you, I can find problems by your advice!